# Error in JSP code

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I am getting `(html:form)` as unknown tag error. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make tag library available and also need to import it in jsp

Comment: just follow [this tutorial & installation step , its pretty easy](http://www.allapplabs.com/struts/struts_example.htm) step

Comment: This link is not available anymore.

Answer (score 1):

That's a [Struts](http://struts.apache.org/) specific taglib. Struts is an action based MVC framework which runs on top of JSP. You need to declare the Struts taglib in top of the JSP as per [their instructions](http://struts.apache.org/kickstart.html) (if your *actual* intent was indeed to use Struts in JSP, otherwise you should question yourself what the `<html:form>` is doing in the JSP).

If you indeed intend to develop with Struts, then take alook at [mkyong.com](http://www.mkyong.com/) tutorials (in the top menu choose Struts 1.x or Struts 2 depending on the struts version you're using).

Comment: you're still using the word "legacy" for Struts.. :)

Comment: @The: only for you, I've removed it :)

Comment: I'm trying to give respect where it's due... :)

Answer (score 1):

i think you forget to add the library file(.tld) suppose if your are using struts for that you have to add

<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld"  prefix="html"%>

this will come when your integrate your application with sturts